# Server fetched partials + pagination - how to remove the partial route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am calling a table with pagination using server-fetched partial.

The table is `at www.example.com/mypage`.

I also have a route that fetched the partial via the `fetch()` API on `mypage-partial`, which returns the table with the pagination links and inserts them inside the `#table-container` div:

```
// mypage-partial.blade.php
<table>
 // display the data
</table>
{{ $data->appends(['queryStringKey' => 'queryStringVal'])->links() }}
```

The problem is that the new pagination links contain the API route, so when I click the numbers of the pagination, it redirects to:

at `www.example.com/mypage/mypage-partial`, instead of  `at www.example.com/mypage`

How can I prevent the server-fetched partial links from having the API route?